# Script does not put info in Out-File

Tags: windows, powershell

I have created the following script:

```
#This scripts finds if 2 LST files were created today.

#What date are we in
$today = Get-Date

#Are there two lst files?
$Lst = @(Get-ChildItem 'PATH' -recurse -include @("*.lst") | Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -gt (Get-Date).Date })

if ($Lst.length -eq 2) {

$LstStatus =  "Files OK"
$filename = (Get-ChildItem 'PATH' -recurse -include @("*.lst") | Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -gt (Get-Date).Date } | Select-Object Name)
}
else { $LstStatus =  "LST ERROR" }

#What do I want in the file
$output = @(Write-Host -NoNewline @($today.ToShortDateString()) @($filename.name) $LstStatus)
$output | Out-File PATH\lst_check.txt`
```

`$output` has the info I need and `lst_check.txt` gets created, but it is empty.

What am I missing? Is there some other command I should replace `Write-Host` with?

Comment: `Write-Host` writes directly to the screen, `$output` won't contain anything

Comment: so how can I populate $output with @($today.ToShortDateString()) @($filename.name) $LstStatus ?

Comment: `"$($today.ToShortDateString()) $($filename.Name) $LstStatus" |Out-File filename.ext`

Comment: Congratulations! :-) Wrote up a proper answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Write-Host` writes your ouput directly to the *host* application, in your case probably the console.

To output to a file, store the values as a string instead:

```
$output = "$($today.ToShortDateString()) $($filename.name) $LstStatus"
Write-Host "This is the output: $output"
$output | Out-File PATH\lst_check.txt
```

Comment: thanks, i did not know how to save as a string, now i do